# GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") not working with Outlook open

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the below code in an Excel file which can be accessed and used by multiple people. The extract checks to see if Outlook is open before proceeding with the rest of the code.

```
Dim oOutlook As Object

'Checks to see if Outlook is open
On Error Resume Next
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not open."
    Exit Sub
End If
Set oOutlook = Nothing
```

The code seems to work for everyone apart from one person/computer. For this one person/computer, even with Outlook open, the line of code
    `Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`
does not seem recognise that it is open. I've checked the usual things: made sure the VBA references are set up correctly, security settings seem to be the same as everyone else.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I use this to avoid this problem :

```
On Error Resume Next
Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

But actually I have no clue where the issue come from... It just pass by for me sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Function CreateOutlook() As Object
    Dim Outlook As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Outlook Is Nothing Then Shell "Outlook"
    On Error Resume Next
        Do While Outlook Is Nothing
            Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Outlook.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1
    Set CreateOutlook = Outlook
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim Outlook As Object
    Set Outlook = CreateOutlook()
    ... 'Other operations
End Sub
```

All works perfectly.

Edit:

GetObject sometimes not return correctly the object. I use GetObject for check if application is opened. When the application is opened i create a object that works correctly.

Comment: Can you explain why you `Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` right after waiting for the `Shell` function to finish with your `Do While` Loop? Also: Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop if Outlook is not installed on a machine?

Comment: Shell "Outlook" start the process while GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") run until the process is completely started.

Comment: Wouldn't `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` creates a new instance of Outlook? Making your two `GetObject( , "Outlook.Application")` and your `Shell` command obsolete?

Comment: I want obtain the current instance of Outlook and not create a new instance, i want also check if i can access at the object methods.

Comment: You should check `If Outlook Is Nothing` before setting it again, because that call overwrites your prior calls.

Comment: Every time that the GetObject fails, the object will always remain Nothing. Only when it succeeds, the object will get the instance of Outlook and consequently the while loop ends.

Comment: Yes, but after your loop you `Set` the object again, thus making your loop and any prior `GetObject()` calls obsolete.

Comment: Because GetObject sometimes not return correctly the object. I use GetObject for check if application is opened.

Comment: In that case you should definitely add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On systems with UAC both applications should be run under the same security context. For example, if one of the applications is run with admin privileges, another should be run with admin privileges as well to access a running instance.

You may find the [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have to do this because that error came up when the first getobject failed, so I started repeating it 3 or more times, and never had an issue again:

```
on error resume next
Dim AutoCAD As Object
Dim Thisdrawing As Object
Dim activedocument As Object
Dim acadapplication As Object
Dim acadapp As Object
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.14")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.15")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.16")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.17")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.18")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.19")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.20")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.21")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.22")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.23")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.24")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.25")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.26")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.27")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.28")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.29")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application.30")

Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application")
Set acadapp = GetObject(, "autocad.application")
```

Just in case there were newer versions I tried them all once, then repeated the usual a number of times. Never had a fail again.

Comment: Wouldn't a loop with a max count have been easier than all these reps?