# How do I paste two ranges from excel as images without space between

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a header row followed by a bunch of data rows. I want loop through the data rows and paste each one + a copy of the header row as images (or preferably one image) into separate mailitems.

So each mail will contain something like:

| Header 1 | Header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell in row 17 | Cell in row 17 |

My code below kind of works, but I can't figure out how to paste them without a gap between them, so it looks like one table.

I have no clue about what I am doing here. But if I can get this paste operation to work, I can figure out the looping part.

```
Sub CopyRangeToOutlook_single()
    
    'Declare Outlook Variables
    Dim olookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olookItm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olookIns As Outlook.Inspector
    
    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdRng As Word.Range
    
    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    Dim ExcRng2 As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Get the Active Instance of Outlook
    Set olookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    'If error create a new instance of Outlook
    If Error.Clear = 429 Then
        
        'Clear Error
        Err.Clear
        
        'Create a new instance of Outlook
        Set olookApp = New Outlook.Application
        
    End If
    
    'Create a new email
    Set olookItm = olookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    'Create a reference to the Excel Range that we want to export
    Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Rows(1)
    Set ExcRng2 = Sheet1.Rows(3)
    
    With olookItm
        
        'Define some basic information
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = mail@example.com
        .To = mail@example.com
        .Subject = "Consultant extension"
        .Body = "In Consultancy Management, we are looking"
        
        
        'Display email
        .Display
        
        'Get the Active Inspector
        Set olookIns = .GetInspector
        
        'Get the document within the inspector
        Set oWrdDoc = olookIns.WordEditor
        
        'Define the range, insert a blank line, collapse the selection.
        Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
        'Add a new paragragp and then a break
        Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraphs.Add
        oWrdRng.InsertBreak
        
        'Here is the problem...
        ExcRng.Copy
        oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        oWrdRng.InsertAfter vbCr
        oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ExcRng2.Copy
        oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider `On Error GoTo 0` mandatory where there is an `On Error Resume Next`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891399/1571407. With the specific use here normally a structure where the error bypass scope is one line is better . Although sometimes not usable  https://stackoverflow.com/q/30891245/1571407.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes you are going to copy header and Row x

- Hidden Row 2 to Row (x-1)
- Copy A1:Bx as picture, modify as needed if there are more columns
- Paste on sheet or Outlook

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim x
    For Each x In Array(5, 8)
        Sheet1.Rows.Hidden = False
        Range("2:" & x - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("A1:B" & x).CopyPicture
        Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, x - 2).Select
        Sheet1.Paste
    Next
    Sheet1.Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that is way more elegant. Thank you very much, just what I was looking for.