# screenshots of parts of 2 different workbooks, and paste those in email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Is it possible to make a vba code for this :

I have 2 individual workbooks, in each of them, I need to make a screenshot (not entire screen, just a part), and paste those two screenshots in an email (outlook)

I have spent hours searching for a solution, but I got nowhere, is what I want to do, even possible ?

I'm just asking if this is doable, not asking to write me a code, but if you can point me in the right direction ... (and take in mind that I'm not at all an expert in writing codes, I mostly 'borrow' codes I find and adjust them to my needs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77362925/how-do-i-paste-two-ranges-from-excel-as-images-without-space-between

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can. Run from Outlook and will capture screenshots from any two open Excel (.xlsx) files. Change the CAPTURE_RANGE constant at the top of the script. The code itself is self-explanatory.

```
' Reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library.
Const CAPTURE_RANGE As String = "A1:B5"

Sub CaptureAndSend()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim imagePaths(1 To 2) As String
    Dim currentPath As String
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Excel application found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    currentPath = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    counter = 1
    
    Dim wb As Object
    For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
        If counter <= 2 Then
            wb.Activate
            imagePaths(counter) = currentPath & "\Image" & counter & ".png"
            CaptureRangeAsImage xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range(CAPTURE_RANGE), imagePaths(counter)
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next wb
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = "testing@email.com"
        .Subject = "Capturing Excel File"
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='" & imagePaths(1) & "'><br><img src='" & imagePaths(2) & "'>"
        .Display
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub CaptureRangeAsImage(rng As Object, imagePath As String)
    Dim chrtObj As Object
    With rng
        .CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Format:=2
        Set chrtObj = .Parent.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
    End With
    
    With chrtObj.Chart
        .Paste
        .Export imagePath
    End With
    
    chrtObj.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there also a possibility to get this working without having to open the excel files ?